# How to test asp.net core built-in Ilogger

Tags: c#, unit-testing, logging, asp.net-core, moq

I want to verify some logs logged. I am using the asp.net core built-in ILogger, and inject it with the asp.net core built-in DI:

```
private readonly ILogger<InvoiceApi> _logger;

public InvoiceApi(ILogger<InvoiceApi> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

then I use it like: `_logger.LogError("error));`

I tried to mock it (with moq) as usual by:

```
MockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<InvoiceApi>>();
```

and inject this in the service for test by:

```
new InvoiceApi(MockLogger.Object);
```

then tried verify:

```
MockLogger.Verify(m => m.LogError(It.Is<string>(s => s.Contains("CreateInvoiceFailed"))));
```

but it throw:

> Invalid verify on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.LogError

So, how can I verify this logs logged?

Comment: [`LogError`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerExtensions.cs#L273) is an extension method (static) not an instance method. Moq is unable to mock and hence verify that method.

Comment: IMO Making methods like *LogError*, *LogDebug*, etc as extension methods is a very peculiar design from Microsoft. These methods look like a first class citizens for *ILogger* interface. What's left in this interface if everything is an extension?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As @Nkosi've already said, you can't mock an extension method. What you *should* mock, is [the `ILogger.Log` method](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/26eeb9d13259969b5b1d3397dc60bbb77d7a5f64/src/Logging/Logging.Abstractions/src/ILogger.cs#L22), which [`LogError` calls into](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/26eeb9d13259969b5b1d3397dc60bbb77d7a5f64/src/Logging/Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerExtensions.cs#L245-L248). It makes the verification code a bit clunky, but it should work:

```
MockLogger.Verify(
    m => m.Log(
        LogLevel.Error,
        It.IsAny<EventId>(),
        It.Is<FormattedLogValues>(v => v.ToString().Contains("CreateInvoiceFailed")),
        It.IsAny<Exception>(),
        It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>()
    )
);
```

(Not sure if this compiles, but you get the gist)

Comment: It does! The only thing is to add `It.IsAny<Exception>()` as penultimate argument.

Comment: Thanks @khellang using .Log instead of .LogError works!

Comment: This breaks in .NET Core 3.0 due to FormattedLogValues becoming internal.

Comment: That sucks. Looks like a newer version of Moq (v4.13) allows you to use `It.IsAnyType` instead of `FormattedLogValues`, so you could still mock it in 3.0. See https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1319.

Comment: `It.IsAnyType` work! This is a working solution from the link mentioned above: `_loggerMock.Verify(x => x.Log(LogLevel.Warning, It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()))));`

Answer (score 14):

After some upgrades to .net core 3.1 FormattedLogValues become internal. We can not access it anymore. I made a extensions method with some changes.
Some sample usage for extension method:

```
mockLogger.VerifyLog(Times.Once);
```

```cs
public static void VerifyLog<T>(this Mock<ILogger<T>> mockLogger, Func<Times> times)
{
    mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Log(
        It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
        It.IsAny<EventId>(),
        It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, t) => true),
        It.IsAny<Exception>(),
        It.Is<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>((v, t) => true)), times);
}
```

Comment: Any help on a .Callback setup since the internalization of FormattedLogValues ?   As seen here as well.   https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/918   Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 9):

I've written a [short article](https://ardalis.com/testing-logging-in-aspnet-core) showing a variety of approaches, including mocking the underlying Log() method as described in other answers here. The article includes [a full GitHub repo with each of the different options](https://github.com/ardalis/TestingLogging). In the end, my recommendation is to use your own adapter rather than working directly with the ILogger type, if you need to be able to test that it's being called.

https://ardalis.com/testing-logging-in-aspnet-core

Answer (score 4):

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/918) which shows you how you can Verify the logger usage.

Let's suppose we have an `ILogger<MyService>` that we want to mock:

```cs
private readonly Mock<ILogger<MyService>> loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<MyService>>();
```

#### Verify zero call

```cs
loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Log(It.IsAny<LogLevel>(), It.IsAny<EventId>(), 
  It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), 
  (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()), 
  Times.Never);
```

#### Verify log level and times

```
const LogLevel expectedLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
Times expectedOccasions = Times.Exactly(1);

loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Log(expectedLevel, It.IsAny<EventId>(), 
  It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), 
  (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()),  
  expectedOccasions);
```

#### Verify log message

```cs
const LogLevel expectedLevel = LogLevel.Information;
const string expectedMessage = "Information";
const Exception withoutException = null;
Times expectedOccasions = Times.Once;

loggerMock.Verify(logger => logger.Log(expectedLevel, It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), withoutException, 
    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()), 
    expectedOccasions, expectedMessage);
```

Or

```cs
const LogLevel expectedLevel = LogLevel.Information;
const string expectedMessage = "Information";
const Exception withoutException = null;
Times expectedOccasions = Times.Once;

loggerMock.Verify(logger => logger.Log(expectedLevel, It.IsAny<EventId>(),
    It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, _) => v.ToString().Contains(expectedMessage)),
    withoutException, (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()), 
    expectedOccasions);
```

#### Verify exception type

```cs
const LogLevel expectedLevel = LogLevel.Critical;
Times expectedOccasions = Times.Once;
                
loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Log(expectedLevel , It.IsAny<EventId>(),  
   It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), It.IsAny<MyCustomException>(), 
   (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()), 
   expectedOccasions);
```

Answer (score 2):

For those trying to receive a callback for the log calls:

```
            mock.Mock<ILogger<X>>()
                .Setup(x =>
                    x.Log(
                        LogLevel.Information,
                        It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                        It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
                        It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                        (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()
                    )
                )
                .Callback<LogLevel, EventId, object, Exception, Delegate>(
                    (level, eventid, state, ex, func) =>
                    {
                        this.Out.WriteLine(state.ToString());
                    }
                );
```

Comment: I just need to verify logged message content, and this works as I needed.

Answer (score 1):

[`LogError`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerExtensions.cs#L273) is an extension method (static) not an instance method. You can't "directly" mock static methods (hence extension method) with a mocking framework therefore Moq is unable to mock and hence verify that method. I have seen suggestions online about adapting/wrapping the target interface and doing your mocks on that but that would mean rewrites if you have used the default `ILogger` throughout your code in many places. You would have to create 2 new types, one for the wrapper class and the other for the mockable interface.

Answer (score 1):

I have to do a fair bit of logger verification for black box processes at work and, after putting up with the expressions for a short period, I caved and put together an expression builder - [Moq.Contrib.ExpressionBuilders.Logging](https://github.com/rgvlee/Moq.Contrib.ExpressionBuilders.Logging).

The end result is a shorter, fluent, verification statement:

```
logger.Verify(
  Log.With.LogLevel(LogLevel.Error)
    .And.EventId(666)
    .And.LogMessage("I am a meat popsicle"), 
  Times.Once);
```