# How to mock Microsoft.Extensions.Logging using Moq

Tags: unit-testing, logging, .net-core, mocking, moq

I'm currently trying to get the following code to succeed at runtime:

```cs
public delegate void LogDelegate(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, object state, Exception exception, Func<object, Exception, string> formatter);

public abstract class LoggingTestBase
{
    private Mock<ILogger> _mockLogger;

    public ILogger Setup(LogDelegate logCallback)
    {
        _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        _mockLogger.Setup(logger => logger.Log(
                It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
                It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                It.IsAny<object>(),
                It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>()))
            .Callback(logCallback);
        return _mockLogger.Object;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I get a `MockException` once I run the test because the method that gets called is the generic `ILogger.Log<FormattedLogValues>(...)` which I obviously didn't setup.

Reading the [existing answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604198/how-to-test-asp-net-core-built-in-ilogger) and the Moq documentation I came to the conclusion that I should probably just mock the generic method with the correct type argument as shown above.

Here I stumbled into the next problem which brings me to the end of ideas:

In current versions of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` `FormattedLogValues` is no longer public but internal (following [this PR](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/pull/513)) which makes impossible to mock the generic method that gets called in the end.

Has anyone successfully solved this issue?
How?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. I just want to verify that a call to LogInformation is called. According to this -> https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1319 It should probably be solved by Moq..

However, at the end there is an suggestion that you could use It.IsAnyType instead of object.. For you this would be something like:

```
_mockLogger.Setup(logger => logger.Log(
            It.IsAny<LogLevel>(),
            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
            It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
            (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>) It.IsAny<object>()))
        .Callback(logCallback);
```

I've not been able to make it work, but maybe this pushes you in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks for the link! Check out the latest suggestion from stakx for the mentioned githib issue - it works

Comment: A sample solution is here too: https://github.com/WestDiscGolf/Random/blob/master/LoggerUnitTests/test/LoggerUnitTests/LoggerTestExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

The Verify solution explained and solved here:

https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/mocking-ilogger-with-moq
, [the Github source is here](https://github.com/WestDiscGolf/Random/blob/master/LoggerUnitTests/test/LoggerUnitTests/LoggerTestExtensions.cs).

My personal circumstances don't call for verify, just Moq around the Log calls. So I have modified the code to be:

```
namespace my.xTests
{
    public static class VerifyLoggingUtil
    {
        public static Mock<ILogger<T>> SetupLogging<T>(
            this Mock<ILogger<T>> logger
        )
        {
            Func<object, Type, bool> state = (v, t) => true;
            logger.Setup(
                x => x.Log(
                    It.Is<LogLevel>(l => true),
                    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                    It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((v, t) => state(v, t)),
                    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                    It.Is<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>((v, t) => true)));
            return logger;
        }
    }
}
```

and in my xUnit test setup:

```
namespace my.xTests
{
     public class myTests{
        private Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<sFTPAzFn.Logging>> moqlog;
        private MockRepository mockRepository;
        public myTests(){
            this.mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
            moqlog = this.mockRepository.Create<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<MyLoggingClass>>();
        }
        private IInterfaceUnderTest CreateService(){
             var moqlogobject = moqlog.SetupLogging<MyLoggingClass>().Object;
             return new ClassUnderTest(moqlogobject);
        }
     }
}
```