# Testing ILogger<> with nunit and moq

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I'm getting an exception when I'm trying to test LoggerBehaviour in handler.

```
Exception:
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.LogInformation("Begin Request: Id: {UniqueId}, request name: {RequestName}", new[] { It....

System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.LogInformation("Begin Request: Id: {UniqueId}, request name: {RequestName}", new[] { It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>() })
Extension methods (here: LoggerExtensions.LogInformation) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
   at Moq.Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method, Expression expression) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Guard.cs:line 87
   at Moq.MethodExpectation..ctor(LambdaExpression expression, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, Boolean exactGenericTypeArguments, Boolean skipMatcherInitialization, Boolean allowNonOverridable) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\MethodExpectation.cs:line 86
   at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.<Split>g__Split|5_0(Expression e, Expression& r, MethodExpectation& p, Boolean assignment, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 235
   at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 149
   at Moq.Mock.GetMatchingInvocationCount(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, List`1& invocationsToBeMarkedAsVerified) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 432
   at Moq.Mock.Verify(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 318
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression, Times times) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock`1.cs:line 727
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression, Func`1 times) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock`1.cs:line 741
   at Application.UnitTests.Common.Behaviours.RequestLoggerTests.ShouldVerifyThatLoggerHasBeenCalledOnceIfInvoked() in /Users/genady/dev/audity/Application.UnitTests/Common/Behaviours/RequestLoggerTests.cs:line 28
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.TaskAwaitAdapter.GenericAdapter`1.GetResult()
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Execution.SimpleWorkItem.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<PerformWork>b__0()
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.ContextUtils.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<DoIsolated>b__0(Object _)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

My Test:

```
using Application.Common.Behaviours;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;

namespace Application.UnitTests.Common.Behaviours; 

public class RequestLoggerTests {
    [Test]
    public async Task ShouldVerifyThatLoggerHasBeenCalledOnceIfInvoked() {
        // Arrange
        var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<TestRequest>>();
        var request = new TestRequest();
        var response = new TestResponse();
        var nextDelegateMock = new Mock<RequestHandlerDelegate<TestResponse>>();
        var cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;

        nextDelegateMock.Setup(x => x()).ReturnsAsync(response);

        var behaviour = new LoggingBehaviour<TestRequest, TestResponse>(loggerMock.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await behaviour.Handle(request, nextDelegateMock.Object, cancellationToken);

        // Assert
        nextDelegateMock.Verify(x => x(), Times.Once);
        
        loggerMock.Verify(x => x.LogInformation("Begin Request: Id: {UniqueId}, request name: {RequestName}", It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
        loggerMock.Verify(x => x.LogInformation("Audity Request: {Name} {@Request} , total request time:{ElapsedMilliseconds}", typeof(TestRequest).Name, request, It.IsAny<long>()), Times.Once);

        Assert.AreEqual(response, result);
    }
}

public class TestResponse {
}

public class TestRequest {
}
```

Comment: LogInformation and the other typically used methods here are Extension methods and not part of ILogger<T>. You need to Mock the [Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.log?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) 
 method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test asp.net core built-in Ilogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604198/how-to-test-asp-net-core-built-in-ilogger)